# RSS feed for specific category in channel

Tags: rss

I have a channel that has 20 categories - each representing a client who can post there or have others post there for their attention.

Of these 20 categories/clients one (only one) needs a personal RSS feed - is it possible to have a feed showing the one category only? Docs seem a bit unclear on this.

Answer (score 3):

The entries on a feed are created by the [Channel Module](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html). You can create a template just for it or add the `category_id` as a segment.

Let's say the feed is on `/xml/feed`. The filtered feed can be available at `/xml/feed/25`, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss [...]>

    <channel>
    [...]
    {exp:channel:entries [...] category="{segment_3}"}
        [...]
```

If you're using version 2.9, you can even test to make sure the `{segment_3}` is a number.

```
{if segment_3 ~ "/^\d+$/"}
    {preload_replace:pr-client_category="{segment_3}"}
{/if}
{preload_replace:pr-client_category=""}{!-- default empty value --}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss [...]>

    <channel>
    [...]
    {exp:channel:entries [...] category="{pr-client_category}"}
        [...]
```

It's pretty easy!